# Camunda with SpringBoot: JSON gets cut off after 64 KB

Tags: java, linux, ssl, camunda

We are relatively new to Camunda and working on a project at the moment that is giving us a few headaches.

We’ve got a SpringBoot-application with an Angular-Frontend that is supposed to take the data to start a process and send them to our Camunda-engine via REST-API. Aside from regular Strings and integer values we also need files (mainly PDF and Word), which are base64-encoded in the Angular-Frontend and can therefore become a bit larger.

The problem is, the variables (including the files) are encoded into JSON and when the size of the JSON surpasses 64 KB, we get an “Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING”-exception. Our application is encrypted via SSL (openSSL, created the certificate ourselfs via certbot and added configuration to application.yaml), if that should make any difference.

A few bullet-points also relevant:

- Locally (running Windows 10 or in a VM on CentOS) it is working with no problems
- When trying to start the process via the Camunda Tasklist it also only works if there are no files larger than 64kb attached, without the files the process is starting just fine
- There server where the problem appears is a VM from Strato running Ubuntu, using openJDK 13.0.1 and a PostgreSQL-database
- Usucally we are also connected to our AzureAD (thats why we needed SSL), but switched this off for testing, so this should not be the issue. Mentioning it just in case

Did anybody ever encounter something like that?

---

Here’s the uppermost part of the exception in question:

```
Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING
at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream); line: 1, column: 65] (through reference chain: org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.dto.PatchVariablesDto[“modifications”]->java.util.LinkedHashMap[“file_b5b5576b_Object”]->org.camunda.bpm.engine.rest.dto.VariableValueDto[“value”])
```

Here the SSL-part from our application.yaml

```
  ssl:
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
    key-alias: tomcat
    key-store-password: asdfGH12
    enabled: true
```

Anybody any ideas what might be causing our problems?
Thanks in advance and cheers!

Comment: It's not good idea - to save binary data as camunda variable. Camunda save all old variables values in history. Binary will trash your history. Better send dokumentId, and process can get dokument-content from some service

Comment: So basically it would be a better approach our Frontend saves the documents somewhere else, like an own database or table that is not in contact with the Camunda-DB or tables, and just pass some kind of ID as process variable?

Comment: In my opinion it will be far better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wladmir's comment is correct. You should not store huge amounts of data in the audit trail of a workflow engine and not use it as a system of records. Instead have a service which owns the data and only carry a reference / primary key for the data object in a process variable (reasons include separation of concerns, performance, maintainability, accessibility from other clients, data privacy, encryption,....).

However, if you do store JSON in a process variable, do not store it a as a String but as an object and tell Camunda how it is de/serialized (SerializationDataFormat).

This example shows you how this is done using the JAVA API:

https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/blob/4a62d4b44efb126b50f22a6f17273c7c98f8b6da/snippets/rest-service-task-spring/src/main/java/org/camunda/example/service/RestDelegate.java#L33

Comment: Storing huge amount of data in a workflow engine is not in general a problem. For example the [Imixs-Workflow engine](https://www.imixs.org) is designed to store any amount of data including documents related to a process instance.

Comment: It may not be a technical problem I strongly discourage it from an architectural and maintenance point of view. An engine is not a system of records, should not own business data. E.g. if data privacy and/or encryption are relevant, you also invite a whole list of add. challenges into the sphere of the engine. Those should be solved only once, in the system of records. Then DBMS maintenance, backups, indexing, table space size,.... everything will take longer. Different retention requirements for process and business data... There are many reasons for a clear separation of concerns.

Comment: "The database schema used by the Imixs-Workflow engine is quite simple and constis of only one table named ‘DOCUMENT’. During the deployment, JPA maps the jpa class org.imixs.workflow.engine.jpa.Document automatically to the database and creates the corresponding data table." https://www.imixs.org/doc/deployment/database_schema.html Would you consider this a highly scalable design for large amounts of data with different storage requirements (indexing, retention, access pattern, encryption, data privacy,....)?

Comment: Yes, I do. If business data is considered an elementary part of the business process, than this is a solution that guarantees the consistency and secure control of the data.